# Unable to install kivy on windows 7

Tags: kivy

I am trying to download the kivy but getting the [error 2] no such directory or file found On the step

```
python share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py
```

Comment: Try opening the Command prompt [as administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and run command again.

Answer (score 0):

## Kivy Examples Location

After installing Kivy and kivy-examples on Windows 10, the Kivy examples can be found at:

```
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\share\kivy-examples
```

Replace "usr" with your user name.

## Run Showcase

To run the *showcase* example, do the following (remember to replace "usr" with your user name):

```
python C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py
```